# Sql server get primary key when return error sql unique constraint

Tags: python, sql-server, database

I have a question if it's possible to know how to get primary key when return error sql unique constraint

I have table user(id primary key identify,username,email,password)

**N.B : (username,email) are unique**

I inserted (toto,toto@test.com,pass) result :**1 row inserted in db (1,toto,toto@test.com,pass)**

After i inserted (toto,toto@test.com,pass) result :**error unique constraint (username,email)**

**It's normal because I already create a constraint what I want to know the primary key of the line that trigger the constraint, i mean 1**

Comment: What would you want to happen if your insert statement inserted multiple rows that violated the unique constraint?

Comment: So you can have multiple users with the same email address? And you can have the same username with multiple email addresses? Something seems a bit off here from a data perspective.

Comment: And please tell me your password is not in plain text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the wrong way to handle this scenario. You should test it in advance, but if you really want it:

```
DECLARE @username nvarchar(50) = 'toto';
DECLARE @email    nvarchar(50) = 'toto@test.com';

begin try
    insert into [user](username, email) values (@username, @email)
end try
begin catch
    if ERROR_NUMBER() = 2601
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @Msg nvarchar(500);
        set @Msg = 'The combination of user ' + @username + ', email ' + @email + ' is already in use by the id ' + (SELECT  cast(id as varchar(10)) from [user] where username = @username and email = @email)
        print @Msg
    END 
end catch
```